# Conflict between 'prooftree' and 'stix' packages regarding double quotes

Tags: logic, stix, quotation, ebproof

I'm having the following issue : In the environment `prooftree`, my double quotes transform into greek letters. This started to happen after importing the package `stix`

- When I input `"three"` it compiles into `εthreeε`
- When I input ``` ''three`` ``` it compiles into `′′three}}`

Here are some additional information :

- It used to work, until I imported stix which apparently screws everything up, but which I need for numerous symbols.
- The quotes are fine in the rest of the document.

Can someone explain this weird interaction and offer solutions ?

---

Here is a minimal working example which highlights the working scenario and the not-so-working one.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{proof}

\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

"three" - ``three''

\begin{prooftree}
\hypo{}
\infer1{"three" - ``three''}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

---

This produces the following result :

[image: A minimal working example]

---

**EDIT :** I removed all references to the package csquotes because it made my issue less comprehensible.

Comment: you are in math mode, switch to text mode e.g. with `\mbox{\enquote{three}}`.

Comment: It does not explain why this suddenly behaved this way after including the stix library. The quotes were rendered perfectly well before this inclusion and stix is not directly invoked in this code.

Comment: your code is wrong, and that you got in math mode something that looked more or less okay (I don't)  was simply luck. Even without stix you should get warnings `Command \textquotedblleft invalid in math mode`.  stix changes the math fonts (other packages do this too) and now your wrong code really bites you. Btw: better don't use utf8x, in a current system you can leave out inputenc completly.

Comment: math fonts in pdftex use custom font-specific encodings so if you use an unsupported character such as `"` you just get whatever happens to be in that slot in the font, sometimes you will get lucky and it may look like a " and sometimes you will not, depending on the font. (unrelated but why `ut8x` option?)

Comment: not only the quotes are wrong, the `three` should also not be in math italic, as that is designed to make adjacent characters not look like a word, but like a product of 1-letter variables, so the whole `"three"` construct should be in a text font.

Comment: I removed the use of csquotes in the post. Thank you for your explanations though, especially the one regarding "you get whatever ..." which I didn't know.

Comment: I ended up using \text{"three"} which provides a correct output. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I got on my post I came up with the following answer:

Math mode was screwing the double quotes and the use of stix did change what was bound to them, while the real problem was the use of math mode.

Since I did not use math mode manually, and thus could not turn it off, I used `\text{"three"}` which provides a correct output.